# What do we mean, when we say the access modifier "public" accessible to the world "in java"?

Tags: java, public, modifier

I do know the traditional answer which is 
Class, package, sub class, and the world. What does accessible to the world mean. Does it mean another person in different location can import my class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer to your question, accessible to the world means accessible anywhere within the project.